# Is Embersilk Cloth already dropping before the Cataclysm release?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

On my server Lightning's Blade (EU - Horde) one guy showed me a stack of embersilk cloth.

They already farmed it. I thought it was a scammer but he showed it to me in a trade window.

Does anyone know where I can farm this?

Comment: Cataclysm is out, this question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't try unless you're interested in risking a ban.

Essentially, since the launch of patch 4.0.3a there have been a series of exploits discovered, involving wall jumping, water walking, levitation, and all manner of other tricks, to get into new Cataclysm zones -  most notably Hyjal, Tol Barad, and Twilight Highlands. Additionally, certain fishing spots near zone boundaries have allowed people to fish up Cataclysm fish. This has resulted in a smattering of Cataclysm Herbs, Ore, Cloth, Leather, and Fish showing up on auction houses across servers. Blizzard has been fairly proactive about shutting down as many of these exploits as they can, releasing new hotfixes every few days, but crafty players will do what they'll do.

They've also been actively banning people for this, and historically, have issued suspensions for mere possession of the offending materials, so I'd strongly advise against buying it up.

Answer (score 7):

While the new zones are off limits, it is possible to get to them.  For example I logged out before the Shattering on the Stonewrought Dam (good place to watch the end of the world from...) and relogged to find myself in the Grim Batol zone (Twighlight Highlands).

I had a good wander round and saw plenty of level 85 mobs.  I didn't kill any, but did have the opportunity.  Could be something on these lines.